# Firefox Height Issue?

Tags: html, css, firefox

This is a codepen I'm working on for a clock http://codepen.io/www139/pen/MaxGyW

This is what it is supposed to look like:
[image: clock on codepen]

If you view this in FireFox [it works in every other browser on OS X that I have tested], it looks like this:

[image: clock on codepen]

What can I do to make it run like the first example in Firefox and why is this happening?

Here is my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#projectContainer {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#verticalAlign {
  -o-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
#watchBelt {} #watchContainer {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2vh;
  background-color: #AB9883;
}
#watchStructure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#watchFace {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*background: -ms-linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #eee);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #eee);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #eee);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #eee);
  background: linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #999);
  position:relative;*/
  background-color: #0E1021;
  position: relative;
}
#watchHourHand {
  height: 40%;
  width: 5%;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left: 47.5%;
  top: 10%;
  -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
#watchMinuteHand {
  width: 3%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48.5%;
  -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
#watchSecondHand {
  width: 2%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left: 49%;
  -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
* {
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.noTransition {
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="projectContainer">
  <div id="verticalAlign">
    <div id="watchContainer">
      <div id="watchBelt"></div>
      <div id="watchStructure">
        <div id="watchFace">
          <div id="markers"></div>
          <div id="watchHourHand"></div>
          <div id="watchMinuteHand"></div>
          <div id="watchSecondHand"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a child element for `display:table`, is not set to `display:table-cell`.

update your css by adding `display:table-cell` to `#watchStructure`

```
#watchStructure{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: it works; I will choose you as best answer in a minute (once SO lets me) ;)